# Nodes will not display as images

Tags: r, visualization, network-analysis

I am trying to use visNetwork to visualise a network of countries. I would like to use images for my nodes, and more specifically I'd like to use country flags. If I do the test with a few countries, building from the help notes of the package, it works perfectly. But then, if I do it using my data, it does not work. Can someone help me figure out what I am missing?

The test code:

```
library(png)
library(visNetwork)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)

aPNGFile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hampusborgos/country-flags/main/png1000px/in.png"
aPNGFile2 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hampusborgos/country-flags/main/png1000px/bd.png"
aPNGFile3 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hampusborgos/country-flags/main/png1000px/lk.png"
aPNGFile4 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hampusborgos/country-flags/main/png1000px/af.png"

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4, 
                    shape = c("image", "circularImage"),
                    image = c(aPNGFile, aPNGFile2,aPNGFile3,aPNGFile4),
                    label = "I'm an image")
edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,4,3,3), to = c(1,2,4,2))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
  visNodes(shapeProperties = list(useBorderWithImage = TRUE)) %>%
  visLayout(randomSeed = 2)
```

This is the plot I get: [image: Test plot]

With my own data:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = c(2, 20, 32, 91, 115, 125, 149, 153), 
                 ISO = c("AFG", "BGD", "BTN", "IND", "LKA", "MDV", "NPL", "PAK"), 
                 Region = rep("South Asia", 8), 
                 Name = c("Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", "Sri Lanka", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan"), 
                 ISO2 = c("af", "bd", "bt", "in", "lk", "mv", "np", "pk"), 
                 image = paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hampusborgos/country-flags/main/png1000px", "/", ISO2, ".png"), 
                 group = rep("South Asia", 8))

edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(2, 32, 2, 91, 91, 115, 20, 20, 20, 2, 32, 32, 20, 20, 91, 125, 149, 153),
  to = c(91, 91, 153, 149, 115, 153, 91, 115, 153, 32, 20, 125, 149, 20, 125, 149, 153, 115)
)

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
  visNodes(shapeProperties = list(useBorderWithImage = TRUE)) %>%
  visLayout(randomSeed = 2)
```

I get this: [image]